# How to stop speech recognition with a button on Android?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

I currently use RecognizerIntent to perform STT on an Android app. When a user clicks a button, the Google Voice Input screen pops up, the user can speak and it is transcribed. When it is quiet enough, the popup shuts and the input is processed.

However, the popup will not shut / process the results if there is still some background noise (despite having transcribed the necessary words).
If I click the screen, the popup disappears, but the results are not processed.

Is there a way to click the popup window (the microphone that pops up) to force the app to stop recording and process the results it has already transcribed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not about the Android OS but about a particular end-user app that implements the RecognizerIntent activity.

Google app v10.98.7.21 on Android v10 does not seem to have this feature that you're after. However, there is no way of knowing for sure because it's a closed source app, without detailed release notes nor end user documentation, nor does it make any commitments regarding its future behavior. A good idea for your app is not to depend on such 3rd party apps.